# I have some problem with kernel building in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, compiling, kernel-panic

I have a problem while building kernel in ubuntu.

First, I installed linux-source package and unzipped source code.

I copied config from `/boot/config-[Version]-generic` to `[source code dir]/.config`
When I tried building kernel with `make-kpkg & dpkg` there was no problem.

Next I tried building kernel with `make ; make modules_install ; make install ; reboot`. But, when I reboot my computer after `make install` computer cannot be booted because of this error.

[image: Kernel panic after kernel compile]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

In grub the boot loader, there should be an option to load an older kernel. Select the 2nd newest. It should load as before.

Comment: I know how recover my crash editing boot loader option but I want to know that why kernel panics when it is installed by make install? Thanks anyway for your comment.

Comment: Have you tried to re-build the stock kernel, from the some config file? (Do this before changing anything). And add your comment to the question.

Comment: What config file should I use when building kernel? I used my own config file in /boot directory when compiling kernel but kernel panic after boot. With same config file make-kpkg & dpkg works fine but make & make modules_install & make install panics.